# Java IOException Stream Closed in Server Client program

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, networking, inputstream

I am trying to make a Server Client program that allows sending multiple messages from server to client or vice versa without waiting for a response. The program works fine when the first client is connected and disconnected. But when I connect the client again, I get the error. Here is my server code:

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketException;

import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import java.io.BufferedReader;

class Q2Server implements Runnable{
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private Socket socket;
    private DataOutputStream out;
    private BufferedReader in1;
    private DataInputStream in2;
    private Thread read, write;
    private String clientMsg, serverMsg;

    public Q2Server (int port) throws IOException{
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);

        while(true) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Waiting for client on port " + serverSocket.getLocalPort() + "...");
                socket = serverSocket.accept();

                System.out.println("Just connected to " + socket.getRemoteSocketAddress());

                out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                out.writeUTF("Thanks for connecting to " + socket.getLocalSocketAddress());

                clientMsg = "";
                serverMsg = "";

                read = new Thread(this);
                write = new Thread(this);

                read.start();
                write.start();

                read.join();
                write.join();

            } catch(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch(InterruptedException ie) {
                ie.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    public void run () {
        try {
            if(Thread.currentThread() == write) {
                while(true) {
                    try {
                        if(clientMsg.equals("close")) {
                            break;
                        } else {
                            in1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                            out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                            serverMsg = in1.readLine();
                            out.writeUTF(serverMsg);
                            if(serverMsg.equals("close")) {
                                socket.close();
                                in1.close();
                                in2.close();
                                out.close();
                                System.out.println("Closing connection...");
                                break;
                            }    
                        }
                    } catch (SocketException s) {
                        break;
                    } 

                } 

            } else {
                while(true) {
                    try {
                        if(serverMsg.equals("close")) {
                            break;
                        }
                        in2 = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                        clientMsg = in2.readUTF();
                        System.out.println("Client: " + clientMsg);
                        if(clientMsg.equals("close")) {
                            socket.close();
                            in1.close();
                            in2.close();
                            out.close();
                            System.out.println("Closing connection...");
                            break;
                        }
                    } catch(SocketException s) {
                        break;
                    } 

                } 

            }
        } catch (IOException i) {
            i.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Q2Server server = new Q2Server(8080);
    }
}
```

Client code:

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.rmi.UnexpectedException;


import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.lang.Thread;

class Q2Client implements Runnable {
    private Socket socket;
    private Thread read, write;
    private BufferedReader in1;
    private DataInputStream in2;
    private DataOutputStream out;
    private String clientMsg, serverMsg;

    public Q2Client(int port) {
        try {
            socket = new Socket("localHost",port);
            System.out.println("Connected to port: " + port);

            clientMsg = serverMsg = "";

            read = new Thread(this);
            write = new Thread(this);

            in2 = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));

            System.out.println(in2.readUTF());

            read.start();
            write.start();

            read.join();
            write.join();

        } catch(UnexpectedException u) {
            u.printStackTrace();
        } catch(IOException i) {
            i.printStackTrace();
        } catch(InterruptedException ie) {
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            if(Thread.currentThread() == write) {
                while(true) {
                    try {
                        if(serverMsg.equals("close")) {
                            break;
                        }
                        in1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                        out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                        clientMsg = in1.readLine();
                        out.writeUTF(clientMsg);
                        if(clientMsg.equals("close")) {
                            socket.close();
                            in1.close();
                            in2.close();
                            out.close();
                            System.out.println("Closing connection...");
                            break;
                        }
                    } catch (SocketException s) {
                        break;
                    } 

                } 
            } else {
                while(true) {
                    try {
                        if(clientMsg.equals("close")) {
                            break;
                        }
                        in2 = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                        serverMsg = in2.readUTF();
                        System.out.println("Server: " + serverMsg);
                        if(serverMsg.equals("close")) {
                            socket.close();
                            in1.close();
                            in2.close();
                            out.close();
                            System.out.println("Closing connection...");
                            break;
                        }
                    } catch (SocketException s) {
                        break;
                    }

                } 
            }
        } catch (IOException i) {
            i.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Q2Client client = new Q2Client(8080);
    }
}
```

Here is the stacktrace of the exception:

> java.io.IOException: Stream closed
>           at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.getBufIfOpen(BufferedInputStream.java:176)
>           at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:342)
>           at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
>           at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
>           at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
>           at java.base/java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:185)
>           at java.base/java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
>           at java.base/java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:326)
>           at java.base/java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:392)
>           at Q2Server.run(Q2Server.java:65)
>           at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)

When either of the server or client sends "close" the connection closes. The client can connect again. But when I run the client code again, I get the exception. What is going wrong and how do I fix this?

Comment: You have shared state but no synchronization. This code is written in a most confusing manner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting an exception because you're trying to read from a `BufferedReader` which no longer exists, the `in1` in particular. At the first run, all your streams and readers open as they should, but after getting the command `close` from the client, your server closes the `in1`. Then, when the client tries to reconnect, the program tries to assign the value of `in1.readLine()` to `serverMsg` which is a `String`, but since `in1` is no more, the `IOException` occurs since the `BufferedReader` is closed and nothing can be read from it.

I suppose since you want to leave the server running while the client(s) can connect and disconnect at any given time, which totally makes sense, maybe you shouldn't close the `BufferedReader` which supplies keyboard commands to the server in your case. Closing it doesn't make sense to me, since you're not stopping the whole server when the client disconnects, you just close the connection, but the server still should be able to accept commands.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I did that and now I am not getting error. But after the server sends "close" to the client, server disconnects, but client takes one more input before closing. Same happens when client sends "close", the server takes one more input before closing.

Comment: @ShantanuShinde yes, I've noticed that too. It's just the way you have written your code. The debugger can help you see this for yourself and, probably, fix this behaviour.

Comment: I tried that, the other thread keeps on executing even after the first closes. how do I fix that? I put an if statement but it seems to switch inside the if.

Comment: @ShantanuShinde what is the point of this construction? 

`if(serverMsg.equals("close")) {
                            break;`     
          
Your porgram doesn't do anything when a client gets a closing command from server and vice versa.

Comment: it closes the socket. also, the value of `serverMsg` or `clientMsg` becomes "close". so the other thread will go into `if` and `break`.

Comment: @ShantanuShinde `break` doesn't stop any threads, it just makes the program hop out of the `switch` operator - `if` in this case.

Comment: It will break out of the `while` loop and stop the thread as all code has been executed

Comment: @ShantanuShinde it is possible because even though the thread should stop, some streams/readers remain open since they aren't closed manually. To be honest using this many `break` statements makes the code more complicated to understand, which totally doesn't help with debugging.